# Imagemagick: Create thumbnail of restricted width, but any height

Tags: images, imagemagick, thumbnails

To create a thumbnail from an image file, you can run the following ImageMagick command: `convert -strip -thumbnail 600x600> filename.png`.

However, I am in a situation in which I want to limit how wide an image is, but the height is not restricted.

How can I instruct ImageMagick to resize larger images to a specific width, without restricting the height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can specify just a width to change only images wider than that value:

```
convert -strip -thumbnail '600x>' filename.png out.png
```

Comment: This is indeed exactly what I was looking for :-)